# Software & updates shows intel 8265 / 8275 wireless driver not working: don't use device or contnue using a manually installed driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, intel, iwlwifi

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 on my Matebook X Pro running an Intel 8265 / 8275 wireless card. The wifi is working fine on my device, a little slow. However, when I go into the Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates. It says that the wireless device is not working and gives me three options only two of which I can select Do not use the device or continue using a manually installed driver.

Is there anything I need to be fixing since it says the device is not working?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you'd like to address speed, please start a new question.  We'll be happy to help. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: PuppetCode, did you ever open a bug report? If so, what is the number? I would like to indicate that I am also affected by this bug, so it gets some attention (as more users indicate impact).

Comment: @PJSingh Please see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1859308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your wireless is working, there is no need at all to "fix" it. Here are some additional comments: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2441173&highlight=additional+drivers